# Is it expected to have visual glitches while constantly moving one window from a retina monitor to a non-retina one?

Tags: hardware, macbook-pro, graphics, display

It's a new macbook pro retina with gt750m, mid 2014

I'm moving firefox constantly from one monitor to the other, it glitchces similar to [#50956](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50956/glitches-in-os-x-memory-or-ssd) and [#81021](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81021/brand-new-macbook-pro-retina-glitches) - Doesn't seem to happen with Chrome however I didn't push/try further

The retina screen renders everything differently, so a re-rendering occurs at each switch, doing this consecutively causes this very temporary glitch

Since it's a new/week old macbook pro, I'm wondering whether it's a hardware or a software issue

---

Tested further, happens always with firefox, never with chrome, I also recall a similar momentary glitch during a genie effect once, happens on both monitors, the glitch is confined to the program/animation, so I'm hoping it's a software issue, all temperatures are always very low, below 50C

---

Disabling hw accelleration at Firefox prevents the issue, so the question is, is it a hardware issue or a hardware incompatibility issue, I would be glad if someone with a late-macbook/gt750m/external-lcd can test the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

If I can direct your attention to this thread on the apple support forums

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5547471?start=0&tstart=0

There seem to be issues like this across many different platforms and in many different circumstances. Having read every post on this issue in the forum linked I'd have to say that the energy efficiency softwares and firmwares between all of the different devices result in random and irritating UI lag. Not really a solution though.

Comment: Yeah, I've also researched similar issues after asking the question, it seems it happens a lot, I'm guessing therefore it's a normal issue, especially custom software like Firefox/Photoshop seems to be affected the most